# How do I bind to a RowDefinition's height?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, grid, height

In this example code, I'm trying to offset the `Grid`'s `Canvas` position by the height of one of its rows.  Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  As you can see, I tried moving the  binding lower in the xaml file, just in case the `RowDefinitions` needed to be defined first.  Either way, it doesn't seem to matter because `Canvas.Top` is always 0.

```
<Canvas>
   <Grid Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=DetailsRow, Path=ActualHeight}">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition x:Name="NameRow" />
         <RowDefinition x:Name="DetailsRow" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Grid.Row="0">Button</Button>
      <Button Grid.Row="1">Button</Button>

      <!-- I expected this to maybe work, but no dice
      <Canvas.Top>
         <Binding ElementName="DetailsRow" Path="ActualHeight" />
      </Canvas.Top>
      -->

   </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ActualHeight` is not a dependency property so it's probably not triggering any kind of change notification. `ActualHeight` actually starts at 0 until the grid is measured so that could be one explanation. Unlike `FrameworkElement`, which does define `ActualHeight` as a dependency property, `RowDefinition` doesn't derive from `FrameworkElement` and just defines `ActualHeight` as a normal property with no change event.

I've actually thought about the fact that there should be a BindingMode.Polling option where the binding system would poll the source property at certain intervals. But unfortunately you may just be stuck doing it in code.

Comment: I didn't notice it wasn't a dependency property. Hm. Ok, I will keep looking, but I think you're probably right about needing to do it in code.

Comment: I ended up putting a panel within that row, naming it, and then binding against its height. I get binding trace errors on start-up, but after the window is fully created everything seems to work out fine. If I can figure out how to remove those errors I'll post my solution here.

Comment: @moswald I assume you used `Grid.ColumnSpan` to do that?... If so, that's a great answer which you should post more prominently on this page.

Comment: I honestly have no idea, it's been almost 7 years now.  I'm pretty sure I wrapped the contents of the `DetailsRow` row (or maybe it was behind the contents, hidden), and then bound to it's height.